# How to change from http to https in django project?

Tags: django

I have a project with all HTTP requests and responses(url). I need to convert it to HTTPS. Is there any way to achieve this in django ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually your templates are agnostic regarding the protocol scheme, as you rely on the url template tag. If you want to enforce django [to redirect everything to SSL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/security/#ssl-https) you might want to set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` in your settings.

Everything else is related to your webserver configuration - which needs a valid certificate and a corresponding configuration. Here is a [sample for nginx](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This is something that is usually handled in webserver, not django code itself. (Although you can do it simply with a middleware or using `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` settings option as mentioned by @dahrens)

For example, ngnix configuration that redirects all `http` requests to `https` is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```